# Need to distinguish like icon from unliked icon

Tags: protractor

I need to click like icon but after checking the condition, if this is already liked or not. So i need two different locator paths to differentiate between the two. The only thing different is the classes but the class name has spcae in between and the protractor cannot locate the space class name, even after adding dots for space.

My protractor code and html structure is in the picture:

[image: My protractor code and html strcuture in the picture]

Comment: Do you need to locate those two or this is actually one element and you need to click it if its not yet clicked?

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you're trying to achieve. If you update your post showing html of liked icon and not liked icon and what your script is doing i can give you a solution.

If your element is `<i class="fa fa-heart liked">`.

There are three ways to locate such elements using CSS.

`$heart = $('i[class="fa fa-heart liked"]');`

`$heart = $('.fa.fa-heart.liked"]');`

`$heart = $('i[class*="fa-heart"][class*="liked"]');` // contains partially

Also you have an option using xpath

Comment: code: 

 //will hit the  like icon for the respective entity

  inline ` if(!like_icon.get(0).isEnabled()) {

        like_icon.get(0).click();

         browser.sleep(2000);
    }` 

    //in case the entity is already liked, will uncheck the icon and then again click the same

   inline `else {
        unlike_icon.get(0).click();
          like_icon.get(0).click();
           browser.sleep(2000);
    }`